# Update all subsequent rows on deleting a row in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, accounting

I have built an accounting system, where in a SQL Table, two of the columns are : 
Amount and Balance Left in the following manner :

```
ID    Amount    Balance Left  
101    20        100  
102    20         80  
103    10         70  
104    30         40  
105    25         15  
106     5         10
```

Such that: `Balance Left = previous Balance Left - Amount`.

Now if I delete a row with Id say 103, I would want amount 10 added to all the subsequent rows.
What is the best possible way to do that (in SQL Server 2008 or otherwise)?

P.S. :

1. I'm aware that I can add a trigger to update each row, but looking for a better alternative, **if any**.
2. Code in C#.

In reply to some of the questions and common answers : 
1. Considering there are a million rows below my deleted row - Would it be better to do it in C# via LINQ? or would a SQL trigger work faster?
2. I know its preposterous to save the balance left with each entry, but thats how the user of the DB/software demands it.

Comment: "best possible" - what are your criteria for best possible?

Comment: How are you identifying subsiquint records?  Are you using the ID or do you have a DateTime Field?

Comment: you should probably store only the `Amount` and compute `Balance left` with a view or stored procedure, when you need it.

Comment: Do you mean you want the update/delete code to be written in C#, or just that you'll be calling this mythical SQL query from C#?  If the former, then are you using Linq2SQL, EF, etc?

Comment: Have a datetime field, used ID just for explanation.

Answer (score 5):

The best approach is to not store the balance remaining and instead calculate it in a view when required.

However, if that's not desirable or possible then a trigger is your best bet as you can ensure that your data remains consistent.  Actually, removing all write access to the table and forcing changes via a stored procedure works well too although you're limited to one-row-at-a-time updates & deletes.

The query in pseudocode format would be
update MyTable
set BalanceLeft = BalanceLeft + RemovedAmount
where ID > RemovedID

If you are expecting multiple readers/writers on this table then you also need to consider locking and ensuring that the delete and subsequent update are in the same transaction.  Most of these issues go away if you let a view calculate the balance remaining.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about "best possible", but here's how to do it in linq to sql.

```
using (CustomDataContext dc = new CustomDataContext())
{
  List<Row> rows = dc.Rows
    .Where(row => startingID <= row.ID)
    .OrderBy(row => row.ID)
    .ToList();

  Row firstRow = rows.First();
  int firstRowAmount = firstRow.Amount;
  dc.Rows.DeleteOnSubmit(firstRow);

  foreach(Row row in rows.Skip(1))
  {
    row.Amount -= firstRowAmount;
  }
  dc.SubmitChanges();
}
```

The advantages here are:

- Single transaction - the whole update goes or none of it.
- Optimistic concurrency - if someone removes or updates one of our rows between our read and our write, our changes are rejected.
- Clear maintainable c# code.

The downsides are:

- The records must be read into memory before they can be updated.
- One update statement is generated per row.

---

Since you have a million rows to update, the above is kind of slow and wasteful...  You're going to have to update those rows in fewer sql commands and without reading the rows into memory.

```
using(TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope())
{
  using (CustomDataContext dc = new CustomDataContext())
  {
    Row theRow = dc.Rows.Single(row => startingID == row.ID)

    int firstRowAmount = theRow.Amount;
    dc.Rows.DeleteOnSubmit(theRow);
    dc.SubmitChanges();
    dc.ExecuteCommand(@"Update Row SET Amount = Amount - {0} WHERE {1} < ID", firstRowAmount, startingID);
    ts.Complete();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @T TABLE
(
    ID INT,
    Amount INT,
    [Balance Left] INT

)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
(101,20,100),
(102,20,80),
(103,10,70),
(104,30,40),
(105,25,15),
(106,5,10)

DECLARE @ID_DELETE INT = 103
DECLARE @AMOUNT_DELETED INT = 0

SELECT @AMOUNT_DELETED = Amount
FROM @T WHERE ID = @ID_DELETE

DELETE FROM @T WHERE ID = @ID_DELETE

UPDATE @T SET [Balance Left] = [Balance Left] + @AMOUNT_DELETED WHERE ID > @ID_DELETE

SELECT * FROM @T
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all you don't need to update each row individually, rather you can have a trigger on delete that updates all the underlying rows together:

```
CREATE TRIGGER sampleTrigger
        ON database1.dbo.balanceTable
        FOR DELETE
    AS
      UPDATE balanceTable t
      SET t.BalanceLeft = t.BalanceLeft + deleted.Amount
      Where t.ID > deleted.ID
    GO
```

or if you are not willing to use a trigger at all, you can **create a stored procedure that contains the update, then call it prior to delete, in your application. however in the latter, you should do them in a single transaction to make sure data integrity is maintained.**